# jQuery make option selected - CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Using codeigniter to generate form. The form has a form_dropdown()

```
  <div class="control-group">
      <?php 
        foreach ($clients as $client => $clientValue) {
           $option[$clientValue['clientName']] = $clientValue['clientName'];
        }
        echo form_label('Client Name:', 'client');
        echo form_dropdown('client', $option);
      ?>
</div><!-- /control-group -->
```

**Output**

```
<select name="client">
<option value="Mike">Mike </option>
<option value="Sissel Bygton">Sissel Bygton</option>
<option value="Calli Crass">Calli Crass</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var clientName = json.selected_gallery[0].clientName; //clientName retrieved from DB

//alert box to confirm clientName for this example lets say it's Mike
alert(clientName)//output Mike

//Client Select name
$('select.client').val(clientName);
```

From what I've gathered through other Q&A, I would think that my jQuery would do the trick. Am I leaving something out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="client">
```

Selector supposed to be

```
$('select[name="client"]').val(clientName);
```

If you want to access it using a class then

```
<select class="client">
```

Selector for the above is

```
$('select.client').val(clientName);
```